# Xcode: No such module 'FacebookLogin'

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

I followed the exact steps provided by:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started
to use the SDK using `Cocoapods`.

I then proceeded to add the following code to create a log in bar:

```
import FacebookLogin

func viewDidLoad() {
    let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .PublicProfile ])
    loginButton.center = view.center

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> No such module 'FacebookLogin'

My Linked Frameworks and Libraries is linked to Pods_Swipe.framework.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to open your pre-cocoapods project file, or are you using your pods-generated xcworkspace?

Comment: I am in my original project file (pre-cocoapods file I guess).

Comment: try to delete pod folder from your project directory and re run pod install

Comment: I tried to re run pod install, nothing changed. I am also getting this error when I do pod install: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance. Is this related?

Comment: I have deleted the project and re-created it. Everything works fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you install SDKs by pods ? or by carthage ?

Comment: I have the same issue...

Comment: pod install worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue I was using xcode 8 and I added FBSDKLoginKit.Framework in LinkLibrary in Build Phases of your target. Also the platform in podfile was made to 10.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

If you're using the **use_frameworks**! flag, you must also add pod **'Bolts'** before the FBSDKCoreKit dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps provided by this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started

you can add these pods to your pod file

- pod 'FacebookCore'
- pod 'FacebookLogin'
- pod 'FacebookShare'